# How does the day/night cycle work?

Tags: borderlands-2

There are badass ranks for killing enemies both at night and during the day.Time also seems to progress while fast traveling.  How is the amount of time determined?  How long is one in game day/night?

Comment: Seconds = minutes is all I know for now, as we saw in Lynchwood with the clock. Not sure what hours are day/night.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**The day/night cycle completes every 24 minutes**.

By observing the clock in Lynchwood, you'll note that, after 12:59 on the clock, it goes to 1:00, thus indicating that it's essentially a 12-hour in-game clock. You'll also see that the day/night cycle in the sky corresponds to what we typically expect as the "hours" pass.

In addition, for every second that passes out of the game, the minute ticks once on the clock. This tells us:

- 1 second = 1 minute in-game
- 1 minute = 1 hour in-game
- 24 minutes = 24 hours (1 day) in-game

Comment: To address your other question: I'm unsure about how fast travel works. We tried to use it to get to 'night' for a mission but eventually just waited a few minutes for sunset.

Comment: Fast travel should be instant - it's reconstructing you somewhere else. I doubt it advances the clock beyond the seconds it takes to reconstruct you.

Answer (score 6):

Get in a vehicle.
Drive.
When the headlights turn on, it's night.

Alternatively, go to the Friendship Gulag and kill some robots.
When the searchlights turn on, it's night.

Comment: Your answer is essentially: look up in the sky - if the sky is dark, it's night.

Comment: @5pike With the addition of "when the light turns on, the game considers it to be night", which is slightly more accurate (if not much more helpful) than guessing from ambient light level.

Comment: This tip helped, you are able to see early when day turns to night

Answer (score 0):

A recording in the beginning of the game states that Pandora's days are over 90 hours long.  With every second being a minute, that would make the cycle every 90 minutes.  I have yet to test it to verify, but from general observation of gameplay, this seems reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Shops have daily offers with countdowns starting each new day. I would suggest watching those clicks periodically to see the hours representing night and day.