# What's the timer on the tower in Lynchwood used for?

Tags: borderlands-2

There is a digital timer by the tower to the train station entrance. Is there any purpose to it? What sort of time does it keep?

[image: timer on a tower]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a timer, but a clock (as you would expect to find at a train station).  The time does correctly correspond to the [night/day cycle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/85892/4775), so it can be used to figure out how long you have before night/day.

Answer (score 2):

Well That is a Clock and it could be used for finishing the challenge where you have to kill a bruiser on 5 O clock train.

Its there to let you know when 5'O clock train is coming. :D

Comment: I accidentally got that challenge actually haha.