# Is there a globally-accessible means of tracking time of day in Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2

> Related: [How does the day/night cycle work?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/84974/6274)

I have started a mission which has an optional "complete at night" objective. However, I'm afraid to pursue it just now because it is already night and I don't know how many in-game hours (real-world minutes, according to the linked thread) are left before dawn. I don't want the night to pass away while I'm in the middle of completing the objective and therefore lose the bonus.

Is there a globally-accessible means of telling what time it is, with a reasonable amount of precision, in-game? I know the clock in Lynchwood give some indication, but to travel there (and especially to fast-travel) would take some time and really throw off my plans.

NOTE: Though I would not be surprised to find out that there is a cheat/debug command that will retrieve this information, I'm needing something (if it exists) that will work for consoles. I'm on PS3.

Comment: I don't think so. The lack of a visible sun makes it crazy hard to determine exactly when "night" is supposed to be.

Comment: Though you might be able to make an educated guess based on the appearance of the sky and the shadow of the moon base on the moon

Comment: No sun! I knew there was something about that sky that bothered me, I just didn't know what!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is **no** such method, not even for PC.

Fast-traveling advances the time by some amount that is hard to pinpoint, maybe even backwards, like rounding to several hours.

*As for that Trailer Trashing mission, I've ended fast-travelling to different locations to advance time by different amounts. After the time was "definitely night", I've taken that optional objective.*

Comment: I ended up just putzing around the area, stomping out spiderants and generally pissing off the bandits, until nightfall.